# how to instal or copy font file to windows fonts folder

Tags: python, fonts, shutil

I am performing a simple operation to copy font file(ttf extension) from a downloaded location to fonts folder, but its not working,

```
usrPath = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
src=downloadFont()
print("Downloaded Location:", src)
#dst=usrPath[0]+':\\Windows\\Fonts\\anmollipi.ttf' # this one doesnt
dst="C:\\Users\\Teacher\\Desktop"  # this one works
print("Install location",dst)
copyfont(src,dst)
```

I hope some one can look into and help me out !!!

Comment: Are you certain that the user has write access to that directory?

Comment: Did you get an error message? Can we see it?

Comment: I do not get any error message and moreover I am logged into Admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have read write access to Fonts folder, sometimes even if you are logged in as user on a system with Admin rights you need to change the folder permission to perform the file write operation...

Comment: yes i do have permission on the folder as i login as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in the `USERPROFILE` environment variable since you haven't told us yet, but I doubt very much it should have a ":\" appended to it. That would only make sense for drive letters (e.g. just "C" or "D" without the colon), and `USERPROFILE` is supposed to be a *path*.

Comment: I used this(os.environ['USERPROFILE']) method to get OS installation directory. and so I took out first letter which is going to be OS installation drive from it