# Windows, why can't I move font to fonts folder even though program is run as administrator?

Tags: python, windows, fonts, uac

I am attempted to have my code install a font file (`.ttf`) onto the computer so that it can be used by the program. I am attempting to do this by moving the `.ttf` file into the `C:/Windows/Fonts` folder. In order to do this, the program needs administrator permissions, and so I have used [PyUAC](https://pypi.org/project/pyuac/) to grant this permission. However, I still get `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts'`. Is there a way to fix this, or is what I am attempting impossible?

Code:

```
import pyuac
if pyuac.isUserAdmin() == False:
    try:
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()
        INITIALIZEFONT()
    except: #User denied administrator permission
        pass
else: #pyuac.isUserAdmin() == True:
    INITIALIZEFONT()
```

```
from shutil import copyfile
def INITIALIZEFONT():
    try:
        fontPath = 'C:\\myPath\\Copperplate.ttf'
        copyfile(fontPath, 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts')
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        breakpoint()
        input()
```

My breakpoint confirms that the program does indeed have administrator permission.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts'
> c:/MYPATHHERE.py(19)INITIALIZEFONT()
-> input()
(Pdb) pyuac.isUserAdmin()
True
(Pdb)
```

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479886/how-to-instal-or-copy-font-file-to-windows-fonts-folder) should not be considered a duplicate because the OP is asking how to move the file, not about permissions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, include all `import`s. What is `copyfile`? Do you mean e.g. `import shutil;` … `shutil.copyfile(fontPath, 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts')`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder isn't a real folder.

- it's a shell namespace extension
- that enumerates the registry, and shows you the installed fonts as a folder
- and you can also install fonts by right-clicking them and selecting **Install**
- or you can drop-drop them into the **Fonts** folder.

You can't, and shouldn't, try to copy font files there. You should instead use [**AddFontResource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourceexa)

Bonus Reading from Michael Kaplan (rip):

> [About the Fonts folder in Windows, Part 1 (aka What are we talking about?)](https://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/06/25/646701.html)